# I have a backtracking problem to implemnt in c but i dont know where i am wrong

Tags: c, backtracking

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define n 10
int s[n][n];


int sol_p(int l, int c)
{
    int nrl=0, nrc=0;
    for(int i=0; i<c && nrl<2; i++)
        if(s[l][i] == 1)
            nrl ++;
    for(int i=0; i<l && nrl<2; i++)
        if(s[i][c] == 1)
            nrc ++;
    if(nrl>=2 || nrc>=2)
        return 0;
    if(l>0 && l<n-1 && c>0 && c<n-1)
    {
        if(s[l+1][c]==1 || s[l-1][c]==1 || s[l][c+1]==1 || s[l][c-1]==1 || s[l+1][c+1]==1 || s[l-1][c-1]==1
                || s[l-1][c+1]==1 || s[l+1][c-1]==1 )
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void bkt(int c)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(sol_p(i,c)==1)
        {
            s[i][c]=1;
            if(c == n-1)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                        printf("%d ", s[i][j]);
                    printf("\n");
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            else
                bkt(c+1);


        }


    }
}
int main()
{
    bkt(0);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code.The problem says to generate all matrixes so on each column and on each row there have to be exactly two 1(matrix is initialized with 0).Also the 1 cannot have neighbours other ones(not even diagonally).I think that my bkt function is wrong

Comment: i forgot to say the matrix is of 10x10

Comment: the neighbour check around line 20 is not correct, what if l is 9, then you are looking for 10th element that is out of givin grid. Same for the c.